# Combined selectors for $.each

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I am trying to update the value of an input looking like this:

```
<input type="text" style="width:40px;" class="form-control uniform-input text form-update-price" data-slot-time="21:45" data-slot-date="14-07-26" data-slot-cat="1" placeholder="">
```

I found this code for using multiple selectors:

```
$(".btn-samedays").click(function(){
        $("[data-slot-date='"+slot_date+"'], [data-slot-cat='"+slot_cat+"']").each(function(){
            $(this).val("YES");
        });
    });
```

But, this updates all inputs that *either* have the requested date *or* the requested category.

Is there a way to update only the inputs which have the requested date *and* category combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine rules like

```
$("[data-slot-date='" + slot_date + "'][data-slot-cat='" + slot_cat + "']").val("YES");
```

Also as shown above there is no need to use the each

Comment: Great... That was so quick, that I can't even accept your answer yet :) Thank you and Adil as well. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use multiple selector, rather combine the condition by removing the space and comma between two selector. You also do not need each if you only want to set the value instead you need `val()`.

```
$("[data-slot-date='"+slot_date+"'][data-slot-cat='"+slot_cat+"']").val("YES");
```